# How to make object invisible for secondary camera?

Tags: game-engine

I was wondering if you could make an object invisible to one camera, but still visible to another in BGE

Comment: I don't think you can because objects are related to the scene, I don't know which kind of effect you want to achieve but I bet you could get it done by playing with the layers instead

Comment: Yeah, that or maybe two scenes one for each camera, one with said object, one without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing render to texture you can simply by doing:

```
obj.visible = True
camera_tex.refresh(True)
obj.visible = False
camera2_tex.refresh(False)
```

I am not sure if you can do it if you are using viewports.
How are you setting up your two cameras?

Comment: I'm using http://www.tutorialsforblender3d.com/Game_Engine/Viewports/blend/Viewports249.txt

Comment: I cannot think of a way to do this using the viewport method.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just have an invisible actor present and just spawn the object you want shown whenever a camera is activated. And whenever it's not it will end object. Assuming either [it's an object with no deform or armature], or [it doesn't need collision].